# getenv - Environment variable on Mac OS X and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, environment-variables

`getenv`  is used for accessing environment variables on Mac OS X and Linux, it takes `char*` as input. Does that mean that I cannot store UNICODE strings as value in these environment variables on these Systems?

While on Windows `GetEnvironmentVariable` etc, return wide strings that can accommodate UTF16 strings.

Comment: or what is the encoding of string returned by getenv? UTF8?

Comment: The POSIX spec has this to say about environment variable values: "The values that the environment variables may be assigned are not restricted except that they are considered to end with a null byte and the total space used to store the environment and the arguments to the process is limited to {ARG_MAX} bytes." So UTF8 should be OK in one sense. But it also says: "For values to be portable across systems conforming to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, the value shall be composed of characters from the portable character set (except NUL and as indicated below)"

Comment: For what exact purpose do you want to have an environment variable with an UTF-8 string?

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems were not invented with widestrings in mind, back then. So there is no possibility to create widestring environment variables or read them.
For Windows there is as an expansion to the C-Runtime [`wchar_t *_wgetenv( const wchar_t *varname );`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246422%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), but this won't give you much use on Unix-Systems.

Answer (score 0):

On current Linux (and probably also MacOSX), [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded strings are very usual. (But there are exceptions, see `locale` command, etc...).

As [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) commented, you could suppose that `getenv` is returning an UTF-8 string. But if you want maximal portability, use ASCII only in environment variables.

From the C or C++ programmer's point of view, [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) returns a `char *` and you could want to use UTF-8 related functions to handle it. Notice that `getenv` does not return a `wchar_t*` pointer.

See the [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) man page and notice that the current locale could be defined by environment variables like `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, etc... See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).